# GNU ld: how do I detect multiply-defined symbols?

Tags: linker, gnu, ld

I'm aggregating two very similar sets of source code into a single library archive. There are maybe 5 or 6 functions which are defined with identical signatures in the two code sets, but with slightly different implementation. I need to find these functions, so that I can either change their names (if I need both of them), or to remove one of them.

I thought that `ld` would do the hard work for me, by reporting that the functions were multiply-defined, but it's not doing it. I've currently got a 2-stage link procedure:

1 - an incremental link of the two sets of source files, to produce an archive file. If I already know which functions are multiply defined, I can use `nm` to confirm that the symbol appears twice in the archive.

2 - a final link of this archive file with the object that calls the library code. 'ld' doesn't complain during this step, and presumably is just linking the first matching object that it finds in the archive, without reporting that a second object could also be used.

Any idea how I can get `ld` to scan the entire archive, and report the functions which are multiply-defined? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt a link of all the component .o files (rather than .a files), and you will get the multiply-defined messages.